# Is there a way to capture the MSDOS command prompt string?

Tags: python, windows

In Windows XP when you open cmd.exe you get a console window with a command prompt looking like:

"C:\User and Settings\Staffer\My Documents>*"   where s>* the underscore after the '>' is the cursor.

This is the default for Windows XP. A user might change it using the PROMPT=something or by using set PROMPT=something

In the console window, at the command prompt, entering the internal command "prompt" with no arguments does not return what the current prompt string is.

Is there a command or preferably a Python library that can retrieve what the command prompt is. I didn't want to write a Python module if there was a builtin way of retrieving that string.

The use case for getting the command prompt string is when I use the Python subprocess module to run a python program, and then return to the same console's command prompt while the subprocess is running, I get the cursor on a blank line. I can press Enter and the command prompt will redisplay; but it looks as if hasn't returned from the subprocess yet, which misleads my users.

One solution for the gui part of my app is to run pythonw runapp.py. However I'm left wondering if there's a way to get a clean command prompt when calling subprocess by using already made DOS commands, Python library, proper use of subprocess.Popen() and communicate()?

Comment: That's the Windows prompt. MS-DOS is dead since Windows XP.

Comment: @larsmans - It was dead well before Windows XP

Comment: @Ramhound: ok, they finally buried its smelly remains in XP.

Comment: A better solution would be to wait for your subprocess to finish before you finish yourself... Could you shortly describe how you use `subprocess`?

Comment: Sure; currently: p1 = subprocess('gui_control.py') p2 = subprocess('gui_drill_logger.py') which opens some simple wx windows; some non-logging stuff is "printed" to the console occationally; not logged in a file. I was trying to avoid a bunch of console windows each running other little scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but if you enter "SET" from the command prompt you'll see a list of environment variables, including the current PROMPT (however it won't appear in the list if it's the default prompt).

Comment: +1; it wont appear with SET but echo %prompt% should still return $p$g

Answer (score 1):

From the command line:

```
c:\>echo %prompt%
$P$G
```

From Python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ["PROMPT"]
'$P$G'
```

(http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#process-parameters)

**[edit]**

Ah, I missed your edit.  It sounds like all you want to do is run the script in the background.  I believe you are looking for the Windows "start" command with the /b option - http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: Yes but then I'll need to code a module (and maintain it) instead of telling them to just hit return key. Meaning '$P$G' or whatever they have at thier own station would need to be parsed and printed after each "print" statement (acutally function) Im in Python 2.7.2 btw; And this is doable; I just wonder if there were something like "C:\getprompt" would return not '$p$g' but "C:\Trekkic\controller\>" or use the right piping to force the cmd.exe to redisplay its command prompt. Also missed your edit.

Comment: Make sure to couple that with the use of redirects to suppress output from your running python script.  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
import os
print os.getcwd()
```